# How can we alot the equation number in the answer box?

Tags: math-mode, equations

How can we alot the equation number in the answer box? I need to mark my equation

$$\sin^x+\cos x=15$$ as $1.1.$ But i don't know how can i do this. Kindly help me to the thing so..

**My work**

I am using $\clubsuit$ and number at the end of the questions and I am using the same numbers where I need to refer.  Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: I would have asked this question under discussion in tex-meta.. but i couldnt post there.. thats why i am asking here...

Comment: None of your questions are dealing with [tag:latex3]. Please do some research and choose appropriate tags. Also, What does the `A` in `A.B.` represent? Similar for `B`? I assume this is still dealing with your `exam`-style document?

Comment: What does 'alot' means?

Comment: $\sin^x +\cos x=15$? Interesting...

Comment: @karlkoeller - The OP may have been searching for "assign" or "allocate".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `\tag` macro, which is provided by the `amsmath` package.

E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tag" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1 \tag{1.1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you just want "normal", consecutive numbers, use an `equation` environment and omit the `\tag` instruction.